# Receiving email and downloading attachment through a C# Application

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I am trying to implement an application which can receive the mails sent to a specific email address. The scenario is that the user will send a .ppt file as an attachment to a specific email address, and my WPF application will listen to this email and once it receives the email, it will download the attached file - saving it to the hard drive.

I looked a bit, but all I found was the `System.Net.Mail` objects which only support sending emails through an application using the `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` class.

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: Have you seen the [samples for reading from POP3 mailboxes](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/emails-using-POP3-882705d3)?

Comment: No, I haven't. But it seems to be exactly what I want :). Thank you very much Rowland!

Comment: @RowlandShaw Those samples on MSDN are based on a commercial library, which is well hidden.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var client = new POPClient();
client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
client.Authenticate("admin@bendytree.com", "YourPasswordHere");
var count = client.GetMessageCount();
Message message = client.GetMessage(count);
Console.WriteLine(message.Headers.Subject);
```

A simple tip, that you can follow:
https://joshwright.com/tips/tips-sending-receiving-email-in-csharp/

Answer (score 1):

You can use POP3 or IMAP to check for email messages and then process the email message for saving the attached .ppt file. Click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/?terms=email&languages=csharp) for a list of samples.